# std::stod ignores nonnumerical values after decimal place

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am reading in a value with a string, then converting it to a double. I expect an input such as `2.d` to fail with std::stod, but it returns `2`. Is there a way to ensure that there is no character in the input string at all with std::stod?

Example code:

```
string exampleS = "2.d"
double exampleD = 0;
try {
  exampleD = stod(exampleS); // this should fail
} catch (exception &e) {
  // failure condition
}
cerr << exampleD << endl;
```

This code should print `0` but it prints `2`. If the character is before the decimal place, stod throws an exception.

Is there a way to make std::stod (and I'm assuming the same behavior also occurs with std::stof) fail on inputs such as these?

Comment: Per [your favourite documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), this is expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a second argument to `std::stod` to get the number of characters converted. This can be used to write a wrapper:

```
double strict_stod(const std::string& s) {
    std::size_t pos;
    const auto result = std::stod(s, &pos);
    if (pos != s.size()) throw std::invalid_argument("trailing characters blah blah");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This code should print 0 but it prints 2.

No, that is not how `std::stod` is specified. The function will discard whitespace (which you don't have), then parse your `2.` substring (which is a valid decimal floating-point expression) and finally stop at the `d` character.

If you pass a non-`nullptr` to the second argument `pos`, the function will give you the number of characters processed, which *maybe* you can use to fulfill your requirement (it is not clear to me exactly what you need to fail on).